# Using es6 template literals in mailto: string not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I am generating an email with some pre-populated info in my Typescript-driven Angular 2 app. This will generate an email using a user's default email client. Currently this works when I build the string like this in the component:

```
greetingEmail = `user@example.com?subject=Family%20Greeting%20Email&body=message%20goes%20here`;
```

I am using this within an href in the view. My relevant view code looks like this:

```
<a [href]="'mailto:' + greetingEmail" tabindex="-1">Generate Greeting Email</a>
```

But when I try and use an es6/ecma2015 template literal, the email still generates as expected via my defaut email client, but the various fields of the email (i.e., emailAddress, subject, body) show up as 'undefined'. This is what I'm trying:

```
emailAddress: 'user@example.com';
subject: 'Family Greeting Email';
body: 'This is where the body of the email goes...';

greetingEmail = `${this.emailAddress}?subject=${this.subject}&body=${this.body}`;
```

Is there a particular reason why the template literal option won't work in this case, or why the fields would be undefined at runtime? Or is something else at issue?

Comment: Use it where? There's no context here anybody could use to diagnose. If `this` is the correct binding it should be fine.

Comment: What additional context would you like that would help you here? I've explained that the first option works, but the second doesn't. I also listed both my view and component code, and mentioned this is an Angular app. Not sure what additional context would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: For example, what is `emailAddress: 'user@example.com';` because without any other info it's a JS label with an immediate string that's immediately discarded.

Comment: 'emailAddress' contains the value that will be inputed into the string literal. The same is true for 'subject' and 'body'. All I'm doing is listing these as properties in the component, and then using them in the constructed string literal.

Comment: In what context? What kind of properties? This isn't complete code.

Comment: Maybe someone else can chime in, but I believe you have everything you need to make sense of what I'm asking here.

Comment: Cool, in that case, it works just fine. No reason you can't use interpolation here.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with a tweak inspired by @Rob's comment about "this" and scope. Once I put the variables within an object, and called from that context, the template literal option worked:

```
emailProps = {
    emailAddress: 'user@example.com',
    subject: 'Family Greeting Email',
    body: 'This is where the body of the email goes...'
};

greetingEmail = `${this.emailProps.emailAddress}?subject=${this.emailProps.subject}&body=${this.emailProps.body}`;
```

Comment: Don't forget to `encodeURIComponent()` the value, since a subject or body could always have an `=` or `?` or any other iffy query param value.

Comment: Not to harp, but that's precisely what I said originally, including the part about "this", binding, and context. I'd also add that if you're using Typescript or similar that should be noted in the question and language tags.

Comment: @DaveNewton while I agree that mentioning Typescript specifically would have been a good idea, and I did add it to the tags after, I still believe that, other than that, I gave all relevant context to answer the question I was asking. Additionally, while I found a workaround, it's still not clear to me why the first option didn't work. It seems like it should be pretty much functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue I see is your variables. In Angular2 it would be:

```
emailAddress:string = 'user@example.com';
subject:string =  'Family Greeting Email';
body:string = 'This is where the body of the email goes...';

sendEmail = this.emailAddress + '?subject=' + this.subject + '&body=' + this.body`;
```

Comment: So here you're not using template literals, though. Secondly, while I have the option of defining the type, I don't have to, correct? So still not clear why my example isn't working.

Comment: and dont forget to `encodeURIComponent()` on everything

Comment: check scope of `this`

Comment: I thought I only need to use encodeURIComponent() on user-provided input. That's not the case here.

Comment: I think you're on to the issue here. It's scope. When I put the variables within an object, and call from that context in the template literal, it works. Posted answer above.